# When you are about to test a hypothesis using data from a well-designed study

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Which is true?

I. A Small P-Value would be strong evidence against the null hypothesis

II. We can decrease Type II Error by choosing n = 100 instead of n = 200

III. If you reject the null, you may have committed a Type 1 Error

Comment: I think 2 out of the 3 seem reasonable. But how do you learn anything if I just give the answers. Please try to give answers and reasons so we can check your reasoning.

Comment: I thought I and 3 was true.

Answer (score 1):

"II. We can decrease Type II Error by choosing n = 100 instead of n = 200" is false.

So the answer would be I & III.